# Z-Index without absolute position

Tags: html, css

As a result of CSS trickery like negative margins, occasionally I have some HTML that is rendered below HTML content that occurs later in the HTML document. Even though the original elements should technically be below the later elements, I'd like to display the above the later elements.

Is it possible to make an HTML element appear above another element without having to specify an absolute position? It doesn't appear that z-index has any effect without an absolute position.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Yes: use `position:relative; z-index:10`.

`z-index` has no effect for `position:static` (the default).

*Note that z-index is not a global layering system, but only differentiates ordering within each positioned parent. If you have:*

```html
<style type="text/css">
  div { position:relative }
  #a  { z-index:1  }
  #a1 { z-index:99 }
  #b  { z-index:2  }
</style>
...
<div id="a"><div id="a1">SUPER TALL</div></div>
<div id="b">I WIN</div>
```

*...then `#a1` will never render above `b`, because `#b` is layered above `#a`. You can see a demo of this at [http://jsfiddle.net/DsTeK](http://jsfiddle.net/DsTeK/2)*

Comment: the default is static? wow, I thought all these years it was relative

Comment: @GoldenNewby You're welcome. I've added a demo of my second point to the answer.

Comment: Yeah it worked in my code immediately. Just had to wait the minimum time before accepting.

Comment: Your note (and demo) on not being global are extremely helpful

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that:- z-index is not a global layering system

Comment: In newer browsers it seems `z-index` is allowed even with `position: static`.

Answer (score 14):

I know Phrogz' answer has been accepted already, and a good answer it is, but just for the record: you don't always need `z-index`.

When you have `position:relative` on one element, it will also be displayed on top of all other elements that have no `position` (or `position:static`). Even if you don't have any z-indexes at all!

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzTfs/2/).

Comment: Just for completion, an element with position relative and a z-index of -1 will go beneath the static(default) elements