# Is there a z-index alternative for elements without a fixed/relatic/absolute position?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I need to display one element on a higher `"z-level"`. The problem is, that the element is inside a div with a `"display: flex"` and `"justify-content: space-around"`. The normal `z-index` property is not working and I think that's because the element hasn't a fixed/relative/absolute position.
Is there a way to solve this problem and to give the element a higher `z-value`?

I need to see the hamburger, when the navigation is opened
The code (css is looking weird because I use sass):

```js
const welcomeText = document.querySelector('.welcome-text');
const logo = document.querySelector('.logo');
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
const arrow = document.querySelector('.down-arrow');
const navLinks = document.querySelector('.nav-links');

hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navLinks.classList.toggle('open');
    hamburger.classList.toggle('open');
})
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.introduction {
  width: 98%;
  margin: auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  height: 90vh;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10vh);
          transform: translateY(10vh);
}

.introduction .logo img {
  height: 10vh;
}

.introduction .hamburger {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 8vh;
  width: 8vh;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
      -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
          justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.introduction .hamburger .bar {
  z-index: 3;
  margin: -10% 0;
  background: white;
  width: 70%;
  height: 1vh;
}

.introduction .welcome-text {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.introduction .welcome-text span {
  color: #d1a33f;
}

.nav-links {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
      justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(0% at 98% 55%);
          clip-path: circle(0% at 98% 55%);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links.open {
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(100% at 98% 55%);
          clip-path: circle(100% at 98% 55%);
}

.nav-link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.down-arrow {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-animation-name: arrowAnim;
          animation-name: arrowAnim;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
          animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.down-arrow img {
  width: 15vh;
}

.down-arrow img:hover {
  width: 18vh;
}

@-webkit-keyframes arrowAnim {
  0% {
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-3rem);
            transform: translateY(-3rem);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes arrowAnim {
  0% {
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-3rem);
            transform: translateY(-3rem);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

main {
  padding-top: 10vh;
}

main .roboter {
  text-align: right;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Homepage | Team Jatrian</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header class="introduction">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="./img/Logo.svg" alt="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="welcome-text">
            <h1>Willkommen auf der Homepage von <br /><span class="golden-text">Team Jatrian</span></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="hamburger">
            <div class="bar 1"></div>
            <div class="bar 2"></div>
            <div class="bar 3"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">placeholder</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">placeholder</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">placeholder</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="down-arrow">
        <a href="#team">
            <img src="./img/arrow.svg" alt="downArrow">
        </a>
    </div>
    <main>
        <div class="team" id="team">
            <h1>Das Team</h1>
            <p>...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="roboter">
            <h1>Der Roboter</h1>
            <p>...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="kontakt">
            <h1>Kontakt</h1>
            <p>...</p>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Please add [mcve] so that we can see your css and html.

Comment: Hello! Could you provide us with a code sample?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Z-Index without absolute position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674988/z-index-without-absolute-position)

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't set position: relative?

Comment: The answer is "No". You cannot use z-index property on static elements. They have to be relative, fixed or absolute items.

Comment: @M4FI4S this is false, z-index works on flex items that aren't positioned like in this code

Comment: can you be more clear on what is not working? what are expecting and are you having actually?

Comment: I want the hamburger to be visible when the black nav-menu is open. Now the hamburger isn't visible, so you can't close the nav-menu

Comment: @TemaniAfif Oh, didn't know that, thanks for the info. Knowledge is power

Comment: you need to change the HTML code to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first: [z-index only works on positioned elements](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp), that is having a `position` attribute value other than the default (`static`). The `display` property is not relevant for that matter.

**Update:**
There is once exceptional here - z-index will work on **flex item** even if it's "unpositioned"

The easiest way to "activate z-index" without breaking the current style would be to use `position:relative`, since by itself it will not change the UI behavior.
That is, if you did not provide any offset attribute (`top`/`bottom`/`left`/`right`)

Now for your specific situation - the problem is not only with the hamburger z-index activation, but rather the fact it's located in the `header` element, while the menu items (`.nav-links`) are in the `nav` element.
Since `header` and `nav` elements are sibling here, you should choose which one should be above the other.

You could give `header` heigher `z-index` value to achieve that, for example:

```
header {
    z-index: 2; // higher than nav-links z-index (1)
    position: relative;
}
```

This will get the humburder to be on top, but also the entire header including the text `Team Jatrian`.

**Keep in mind z-index work in [stacking-contexts](https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/):**

> Every stacking context has a single HTML element as its root element. When a new stacking context is formed on an element, that stacking context confines all of its child elements to a particular place in the stacking order. That means that if an element is contained in a stacking context at the bottom of the stacking order, there is no way to get it to appear in front of another element in a different stacking context that is higher in the stacking order, even with a z-index of a billion!

Meaning if `header` is to be above `nav`, it means all of `header`'s children would be above `nav` as well, So you might consider to move the hamburger to be under a different element.