# How to bring element to front, using different stacking contexts and without rearranging elements in DOM

Tags: html, css

I have a complex UI in which I need to re-arrange some of the elements not be overlapped by some others.

Concretely, and simplifying a lot, I have a `main-content` div and a `vertical-menu` on the right. The thing is that these two elements are siblings and `main-content` contains a `popover` that I want to be above `vertical-menu`. This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tteguayco/y9e5owqa/54/) shows the problem.

**Constraints** are: I cannot change the `position` attribute of these elements (it would hugely break my UI) and with that, I wouldn't be able to use `z-index` since it only works with positioned elements. I cannot also modify the elements hierarchy.

I have also read that using `transform` and `opacity` helps "reset" the stacking contexts, but it seems not to be working. Is this at all possible?

Comment: See this post, it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57370623/14264568

Comment: I don't think this is possible while abiding by the constraints you have specified

Comment: Did you try `* { position:relative }` and increase the z-index?

Comment: Yes, it's working on the JSFiddle but not on my app. Unfortunately it's a complex UI, difficult to reduce it to a simple fiddle to state the problem. That is why I set not changing position attributes as constraint.

Comment: What causes the popover to show?

Comment: check tt the end of the duplicate, you will find ideas with 3D transform

Comment: Forgot to mention my app is made with React. I found that Portals do exist: https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html
With this, I can put the popover as a child of the body in the DOM, so that it now has its own stacking context.